# How can I get an interactive shell as another non-root user?

Tags: sudo, privileges

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, with the default security model (root locked, using `sudo` to elevate privileges). I occasionally enjoy using `sudo -i` when I'll need to run a series of commands with elevated privileges, or when I need to rummage around in directories with root-only privileges.

Sometimes, when setting up software that'll run as its own non-privileged system account (`adduser --system --group --no-create-home --disabled-login some-daemon-user`) I find that I need to run a sequence of commands *as that user*, rather than myself or root. I've tried using `sudo -i -u some-daemon-user`, but it just returns a `1` status without any error message.

I've checked the `syslog`, `messages`, `auth`, and `debug` log files in `/var/log` and none of them include any messages that reference `sudo` or the account in question.

So, is it possible to become another non-root user, sudo-style without just setting a password and logging in (as them)? Is my system 'broken' in some way or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ahmm.. the problem is that the standard shell of those users is normally set to `/bin/false` and for security reasons you should not change this. But you can still run for example: `sudo -u www-data /bin/sh`

Comment: Can you give more details on the "security reasons"? Is it any different if I use `sudo` to run a shell as the user, as Florian suggests above?

Comment: The reason is, that any attacker accomplishing a login as a system user, i.e. by exploiting a bug in the login program, is less likely to end up with a valid shell. So, you should leave the setting as it is in the /etc/passwd file, even if it's just for good karma. Invoking the shell directly via sudo is unrelated to this.

Comment: So the issue is setting a shell in the `passwd` file, not actually _running_ a shell as the user. Gotcha!

Answer (score 9):

`sudo -i` runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user, which is `/bin/false` for your system user.

Use

```
 sudo -u some-daemon-user bash
```

or

```
sudo -u some-daemon-user -H bash
```

if you want to set the $HOME environment variable set for the target user.